# EA DTM - profile tool Y axis scale

Tags: qgis, elevation

I am using EA DTM squares as input layers into the profile tool.

I have created a polyline and am using this as selection layer. A profile shape is correctly created.  The X axis is in meters and shows the scale correctly being the length of distance along the polyline.

However, the Y axis comes out from zero to 50000. In real life the elevation should be between 0 and 54 meters.

Any idea what the Y scale is being used and how this can be altered to show meters like the X axis? Both the DTM rasters and Polyline are using OSGB 1936 / British National Grid.

[image: profile tool output]

Comment: The usual suspects of this flaw are the nodatavalue not being ignored when the plot is created or the tool is not using the scale and offset that are present in the metadata of the file.

Comment: thanks, any idea how to check this or fix it?

Comment: I can only assume that the Envonment Agency DEM elevation data is in mm.  Therefore I have converted the Y axis using the raster calculator dividing by 1000.  This now show the X axis unchanged in m (based on the CRS) and the Y axis also show in m.  I think this is the get around

Comment: It's curious though, as supplied EA DTMs have elevation values in metres AOD.

Comment: To check whether your file has scale and offsets, you can use the command line utility [gdalinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html), which you can access with the osgeo4w shell, which should have been installed alongside your QGIS.